# Linq to sql in c# : how to get name via id

Tags: c#, sql, linq

My app in ASP.NET C#, i use linq to sql to pass data from database. My code below

Linq to sql:

[image: Figure]

My code :

```
    public class course_list
        {
            //Id of event            
            public int id { get; set; }
            // Name of event
            public string name { get; set; }
            //type of event
            public string e_type { get; set; }
            //name of the compay
            public string compay { get; set; }
        }
        // Get data
        protected void show_event()
        {
            for_testDataContext db = new for_testDataContext();
            IQueryable<course_list> CourseList = from cl in db.events
                                                select new course_list()
                                                {
                                                    id = cl.id,
                                                    name = cl.name,
                                                    e_type = cl.e_type_id, // how to get name of e_type
                                                    compay = cl.company_id //How to get name of company
                                                };

        }
```

How to assign `e_type = name of e_type` match `cl.e_type_id` and `company` = `name of compay` match `cl.company_id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select new course_list
{
  id = cl.id,
  name = cl.name,
  e_type = cl.e_type.name,
  company = cl.company.name
};
```